# How to clear the column filter cell in Material-Table?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, material-table

I am using this `TextField` to create a custom filter cell for each column in my Material-Table.

I want to use the `endAdornment` as a button to clear the filter, but I have no way of removing the value.

```
filterComponent: ({ columnDef, onFilterChanged }) => (
    <TextField
        onChange={(e) => {
            onFilterChanged(columnDef.tableData.id, e.target.value);
        }}
        InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <FilterList />
                </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton>
                        <Clear className={classes.endAdornment} />
                    </IconButton>
                </InputAdornment>
            ),
        }}
    />
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the piece of code you provided, I see that you set the filters via the following function. *Which takes the columnID and value*

```js
onFilterChanged(columnDef.tableData.id, e.target.value);
```

Maybe you can put this on the `IconButton` component as well

```js
endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton onClick={() => onFilterChanged(columnDef.tableData.id, '')}>
                        <Clear className={classes.endAdornment} />
                    </IconButton>
                </InputAdornment>
            ),
```

> LE: with controlled value

```js
filterComponent: ({ columnDef, onFilterChanged }) => (
    <TextField
        value={columnDef.tableData.filterValue}
        onChange={(e) => {
            onFilterChanged(columnDef.tableData.id, e.target.value);
        }}
        InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <FilterList />
                </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                    <IconButton onClick={() => onFilterChanged(columnDef.tableData.id, '')}>
                        <Clear className={classes.endAdornment} />
                    </IconButton>
                </InputAdornment>
            ),
        }}
    />
),
```

Comment: Thank you Sabbin.  This clears the filter, but the text entered is not cleared.  Is there a way to also remove what a person has typed into the filter cell?

Comment: You will need to have a controlled `TextField` input. Can you get the value of the `filter` from the props? `({ columnDef, onFilterChanged })` - here?

Comment: I do not know.  These are the only two props passed according to documentation.

Comment: Can you please share a link to the documentation?

Comment: Right here https://material-table-core.com/demos/filter/custom-filter

Comment: add `value={columnDef.tableData.filterValue}` to the `TextField` component. Updated response also